# Send Textbox.text along with appropiate clicked button in C#

Tags: c#, button, textbox

Hi (first timer port on stackoverflow :)
I have 10 text boxes and 10 button, each button needs to handle each text box.
every time I click one of the buttons I want to send the text of the texbox along with the button in order to save it to a text file (which I know how to save). Right now I copied and pasted all of the code lines inside each button click function but I guess this can't be the best way. I want to have one function for all of the button who knows which was the appropriate textobx (i.e. textbox5 for button5)
I ended up with many code lines doing the same and messy project.
Thank you all!

Comment: you should create a custom control with a text box and button, then add 10 of those controls to your form

Comment: Look for User Controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Button.Tag

set Tag of each button to id of text box which it correspond

then

```
((TextBox)this.Controls[((Button)sender).Tag.ToString()]).Text
```

OR

set a prefix string + index to your TextBox as Name then add index to Button.Tag call a

```
((TextBox)this.Controls["txt_"+((Button)sender).Tag.ToString()]).Text
```